# Remove Prefix from Addressee

Tags: civievent, addresses

We are on Civi 4.7.29 and Wordpress 4.9.5

We are making badges for the upcoming conference.  We need just the First and Last name to show up on the same line, such as: John Doe.  However, when we select to use the Addressee short code, it shows up as Mr. John Doe.   We really don't want the Mr. part in there as many of our members did not choose a prefix when they signed up and that will look wrong.
If we choose to use the First and Last name shortcodes separately , we get:

John

Doe

That won't work either.  Is there a way we can remove the Prefix from the Addressee shortcode?

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify - you say ~ "we need it to show as John Doe", then say "we get John Doe but that won't work"

Comment: It must be on the same line. If we select first name and last name, they appear one over the other on two lines. Thank you

Comment: What does Display Name token give you?

Comment: ps - can you give a link where you edit these badges? never had to do it so am playing blind which may be why my answers aren't v helpful yet

Comment: This is my first time using them too.  I am going to Administrator> CiviEvents> Event Name Badge Layouts.  Display Name is the one with the Prefix.

Answer (score 4):

You might try the display_name short code (assuming it exists as I do not use WP mysqlf)? You can control the way the display name is built in Administer>Customize Data and Screens>Display Preferences.

Alternatively you can set customized addressees for your contacts? That is a lot of work if you have to do it manually but you could also create a scheduleld job to do this with the API if you have any development skills available?

If you want to make sure the prefix is not in the display name you change the settings for display name. Standard they will probably be:

```
{contact.individual_prefix}{ }{contact.first_name}{ }{contact.last_name}{ }{contact.individual_suffix}
```

Change into

```
{contact.first_name}{ }{contact.last_name}{ }{contact.individual_suffix}
```

Comment: Thank you.   This is the current short code there {contact.individual_prefix}{ }  Is it safe to turn that into {contact.individual}{ } ?   Or should I just uncheck Prefix under Edition Contacts?  Not sure that is even related.

Comment: I would not expect that short code change to be OK but I do not know WP. What are you trying to do now? Not sure why you are taking the prefix?

Comment: If you are not sure why I need to remove the prefix, I must not had been clear in my original post.

Comment: I see what you mean now, see updated answer

Comment: Erk - should your answer point out this will impact everywhere the Display Name is used, not just for the Event Badge?

Comment: Thank you. I think that will work.  It might change everything, but I can't think of anything it would hurt. As long as we can still select Prefix in our exports, we are good.

Comment: sorry. I have to take that back. It's still not working.  It did remove the prefix from the template preview, but when I went to print the fulllist, the prefix is back.   I honestly can't see what that change did.

Comment: The change will probably not reflect any existing contacts in your database. I am not sure if the Update Greetings and Addresses scheduled job also re-creates the display_names. Could you try that?

Comment: And what the change did: describe the way the display names will be built up FROM NOW ON. It does not automatically fix the past AFAIK. If the scheduled job does not do that, you either need a developed fix for that or edit/save the contacts AFAIK.